# convert time to 00d 00h 00m

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want it to show the time in this style: `00d 00h` but I don't know how it could show just 24 hours in a day and not total hours

what shows: `10d 170h`

what I want to: `10d 08h`

`Math.floor((Date.now() - member.user.createdAt) / 86400000)}d ${Math.floor((Date.now() - member.user.createdAt) /  60 * 60 * 24 * 1000)}h`

Comment: I guess you meant ``10d 08h``.

Comment: @programandoconro yes, mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mod the hour total by 24 ,meaning every 24 hours it will 'rotate' back to 0

```js
console.log(Math.floor((Date.now()) / 86400000)+"d"+ Math.floor((Date.now()) / ( 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000)%24)+"h");
```